# Custom views filter with civicrm_entity Drupal 9

Tags: drupal-views, civicrm-entity

Need a hint. With civicrm_entity (3.5) i haven't the possibility to get multiple items in a views row. So i wrote a custom field and now I want to filter it.

I think this works for the contact type (Organization), but I need to filter the related contacts (Individual) by the attached tags.

```
if (!empty($this->value)) {
  $configuration = [
    'table' => 'civicrm_entity_tag',
    'field' => 'entity_id',
    'left_table' => 'civicrm_contact', 
    'left_field' => 'id', 
    'operator' => '=',
  ];
  $join = Views::pluginManager('join')->createInstance('standard', $configuration);
  $this->query->addRelationship('civicrm_entity_tag', $join, 'civicrm_contact');
  $this->query->addWhere('AND', 'civicrm_entity_tag.tag_id', $this->value, 'IN');

  dump($query->options['relationship']) // i get 'contact_id_a' thats correct with the relationship, but how can i use it?

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After I dig a little bit deeper into views and view some other examples - now it works:

```
if (!empty($this->value)) {
  $this->ensureMyTable(); // to get the tableAlias
  $configuration = [
    'table' => 'civicrm_entity_tag',
    'field' => 'entity_id',
    'left_table' => $this->tableAlias, // set the table alias
    'left_field' => 'id',
    'operator' => '=',
  ];
  $join = Views::pluginManager('join')->createInstance('standard', $configuration);
  $this->query->addRelationship('civicrm_entity_tag', $join, 'civicrm_contact');
  $this->query->addWhere('AND', 'civicrm_entity_tag.tag_id', $this->value, 'IN');
}
```